# How could I define an absolute matrix distance?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am dealing with the following problem:

Let us say I have 2 matrices, C and P.

- C stays for Compuetd, meaning that this matrix is the result of some defined computations.
- P means Predicted, meaning that I do not perform any defined calculation, but the matrix is given by a certain neural network. I won't go into details

I would like to define a measure to understand how much P (which should approximate C) is close to C. The main issue, is that this meausure should be an "absolute" measure.

Let's take 2 instances of this problem, namely (C1,P1) and (C2,P2).
The values inside C1 and P1 have a certain magnitude, let's say M1. The magnutude of values in C2 and P2 is M2.

Now, M1 and M2 can be really different from each other, but I would like my distance measure to not depend on them.

A good final result would be a percentage saying how well P approximates C.

Hope it was a bit clear!

Comment: There are many ways to measure distance. You need to add what your matrices actually represent in the physical world. Otherwise, it is unlikely that you will get a useful answer.

Comment: I actually prefer this measure to be independent of what the matrices represents. It has only to be a kind of error based on how P differs from C, but such that this error measures would hold with different magnitude entries

Comment: Then is it significant that you have $m$ by $n$ matrices instead of vectors with $mn$ entries? Can any entry of the target matrix be an exact zero?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are saying. The real application of this matrices is as transfer operators in multilevel solvers. To be precise is always a rectangular matrix, and most of the time can be considered a sparse matrix, unless some very unfortunate cases. But without entering in details it can be just considered as a table with entries, and my distance measure should give somehow the quality of the predicted matrix, based on the computed one (that we already know being correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variety of options and some depend on the physical interpretation of the data. Let $T = [t_{ij}]$ denote your target matrix and let $A = [a_{ij}] $ denote the computed approxmation.

1. The componentwise relative error is the value $\max\{ |e_{ij}|\}$ where $$e_{ij} = \frac{t_{ij}-a_{ij}}{t_{ij}}$$ where we define $\frac{0}{0} = 0$ and $\frac{x}{0} = \infty$ when $x>0$. Achieving a finite value of the componentwise relative error requires $A$ to have a sparsity pattern which is a subset of the sparsity pattern of $T$ such that $t_{ij} = 0$ implies $a_{ij} = 0$. For many applications this is a reasonable assumption, i.e., we know the sparsity pattern but we are not entirely sure about the values of the individual entries. Here it is irrelevant if $T$ and $A$ are treated as matrices or not.
2. The normwise relative error is the given by $\frac{\|T-A\|}{\|T\|}$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is any matrix norm. With this measure you lose the ability to detect that some insignificant entries are not well approximated at all. Here it also matters that $T$ and $A$ are treated as matrices. This is particularly clear when $T$ and $A$ represent images. Rearrange $T$ as a vector and it no longer makes sense to attempt to approximate $T$ using a truncated singular value decomposition. Common norms are the $1$-norm, the $2$-norm, the infinity norm and the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thank you, this seems reasonable! I'll try it soon and see what happens when changing the magnitude of the entries